# Is it possible to market myself if I dont want to reveal my real ID online?

Tags: working-from-home

I am a private person and don't like to add private info online.
You can call me old school but I don't have any social media account or any other online account under my real ID.
Is it possible to start freelancing full time with this situation?
Of course I would reveal my real ID after start working with a client ( not an agency)?
I would appreciate any help.
Alex

Comment: Do you have a web site with a portfolio?

Comment: I made one using one of those no-code website builders.

Comment: Does the website contain a company name or an address or anything identifiable?

Comment: I dont have any contact info listed, I just use it when I apply for a job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything is possible. Whether or not it is a good idea is totally dependent on your market.

Our clients determine what our freelancing business will be. Trying to force them to accept what they do not want to accept means not much business.

If you want to be private, the recommended solutions are to either get a "Doing Business As" name or to get an LLC. When I last did a DBA, it only meant going down to the county courthouse and paying a small filing fee. Once you have that, you can present that name to everyone, take payment under that name, set up bank accounts in that name, and fully function as a business with that name. You can also get a PO Box for that name and use that mailing address.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much David for your help, that is a great idea.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - it is possible to market oneself anonymously.

Whether it is a good idea, is another matter that could depend on geographical location, culture and line of business. If you provide a product that I'll only need once and geography is not a concern, I'm more likely to ignore that you're anonymous than if the service you provide requires more long-term trust.

Personally, I could care less whether my potential business partners have social media accounts - but I generally avoid doing business with anyone who chooses to keep their location secret. At the very least, I want to see a company name and address.

Comment: Thank you @morsor,it was good to hear that not everyone is caring about ones social media status and sharing all their private info online for public to see (and Like, or comment), my service will be in graphic design, I will be providing my real ID to the client when I am working with them , I don't have company and just a one man show.My plan is to have all social media accounts with my screen name to market myself .

Answer (score 3):

The big consultancies do not publicly name their consultants... they advertise their capabilities.

As freelancers we really **must** get away from using CVs or *personal profiles*